# insertar varios checkbox en oracle usando jsp y servlet

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

necesito ayuda en cuantoa  como obtener y transformar los valores de varios checkbox para insertarlos en la base de datos con una coma,por ejemplo:

```html
Seleccione sus frutas favoritas: <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="frutas" value="manzana">Manzana
<input type="checkbox" name="frutas" value="naranja">Naranja
<input type="checkbox" name="frutas" value="banana">Kanana
<input type="checkbox" name="frutas" value="kiwi">Kiwi
<input type="checkbox" name="frutas" value="pina">Piña

<input type="submit">
```

al seleccionar multiples frutas por ejemplo "naranja","platano","kiwi"...etc

se inserten en la base de datos en la columna ejemplo "nombreFruta varchar2(20) de forma que quede como: ('platano,naranja,kiwi').

en el servlet entiendo que se recojen los parametros en una variable que se envian a un metodo y se insertan,pero no logro enviar varios parametros de checkbox para insertarlos con ese formato explicado...

gracias de ante manos..

Comment: Vas a tener que mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora y como lo hiciste. Y si es por guardar esos datos de esa forma, no es una buena idea.

Answer (score 1):

En tu servlet tienes que acceder al parametro "frutas" del request, al ser un grupo de check box lo que te llega es un array, por lo que podrias intentar algo asi:

```
String[] frutas = request.getParameterValues("frutas");
```

Ya con esto podrias recorrer frutas e ir creando un String, que seria el que envias a la BD.

```
String frutasParaBd="";
for(int i=0; i<frutas.lenght;i++){
  frutasParaBd=frutasParaBd+frutas[i]
}
```

**NOTA:** por favor tenga en cuenta las recomendaciones de @gbianchi para la próxima vez que necesite ayuda